# Value of lambda: poisson process

Tags: probability

What is the meaning of the lambda in a Poisson process? How should I find lambda when solving exercises?

Suppose we're given that the time between two phone calls is *exponentially distributed* and is ten minutes on average.

Is $\lambda = 10 \, \text{ or } \, \frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda$ is a parameter that **captures the average number of events in an interval**. For example, take for instance that the mailman observes that a post office, on average, receives $40$ letters per day. Here, what is $\lambda$? Because the average event rate is $40$ per day, $\lambda = 40$.

For more, you may want to check out: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/exponential-distribution-get-some-meaning), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355894/how-do-i-find-lambda-in-the-poisson-distribution) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339771/lambda-value-of-poisson-distribution).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter $\lambda$ in a Poisson process is commonly called the *rate*. So

- the number of occurrences in a unit of time has a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda$, and
- the gap between occurrences has an exponential distribution with expected value $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Your example *"we're given that the time between two phone calls is exponentially distributed and is ten minutes on average"* is telling you $\frac{1}{\lambda} = 10$ minutes or $\frac16$ hours, and you need to take the reciprocal to get $\lambda$ as a rate